# ColdFusion ORM creates wrong data type

Tags: orm, coldfusion

Database: MySql 5.1.47 on OS X

ORM Settings in Application.cfc:

this.ormEnabled = true;
 this.ormsettings = {
  autogenmap = true,
  dbCreate = application.dbCreate,
  automanageSession = true,
  datasource = application.dsn,
  logSQL = application.logSQL,
  sqlScript = application.sqlScript
 };

News.cfc

```
/**
* These are the news items
* @persistent true
* @accessors true
* @output false
* @entityname "News"
* @table news
*/

component
{
 property name="NewsId" type="string" fieldtype="id" ormtype="integer" generator="native" generated="insert";
 property name="Teaser" type="string" sqltype="varchar(200)";
 property name="Story" type="string" sqltype="varchar(500)";
 property name="ProductLineId" type="numeric" sqltype="int" ormtype="int" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="ProductLine" fkcolumn="ProductLineId" foreignkeyname="fk_productline_news";

}
```

ProductLine.cfc

```
/**
* @persistent true
* @accessors true
* @output false
* @table productline
*/

component
{
 property name="ProductLineId" sqltype="int" fieldtype="id" ;
 property name="Label" type="string" sqltype="varchar(50)";
}
```

Debug output from ORMReload()

```
[localhost]:10/05 21:32:00 [jrpp-70] HIBERNATE DEBUG - 
[localhost]:    create table news (
[localhost]:        NewsId integer not null auto_increment,
[localhost]:        Teaser varchar(200),
[localhost]:        Story varchar(500),
[localhost]:        **ProductLineId varchar(255)**,
[localhost]:        primary key (NewsId)
[localhost]:    )
[localhost]:10/05 21:32:00 [jrpp-70] HIBERNATE DEBUG - 
[localhost]:    create table productline (
[localhost]:        ProductLineId int not null,
[localhost]:        Label varchar(50),
[localhost]:        primary key (ProductLineId)
[localhost]:    )
[localhost]:10/05 21:32:01 [jrpp-70] HIBERNATE DEBUG - 
[localhost]:    alter table news 
[localhost]:        add index fk_productline_news (ProductLineId), 
[localhost]:        add constraint fk_productline_news 
[localhost]:        foreign key (ProductLineId) 
[localhost]:        references productline (ProductLineId)
```

The db creation fails when it attempts to create the foreign key relationship.  Notice that the field in news is a varchar(255).  Where did that come from? I tried to set it up as an integer in every place I could find but it always gets generated as a varchar.  I think that is why the relationship fails since the two fields are different data types.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to finally get this working correctly.

1. Be careful of tablename case with
       ColdFusion/MySql/OS X.  It can
       really kill orm.  What happens is
       that if the wrong case treatment is
       used in configuring MySql, Orm will
       drop a table but then be unable to
       recreate it because MySql still
       thinks the table exists but with a
       different case.  This can be
       particularly frustrating as the
       MySql tools will not actually
       display the table with the wrong
       case, but you can still query it. 
       This is a known issue with the MySql
       team.  My advice is to just supply
       all lowercase names for your tables
       and to set your MySql table case
       configuration option to 1 (Store in
       lowercase, case insensitive).  That
       seemed to work for me.
2. Make sure you set your dialect orm
   option to "MySQLwithInnoDb"
3. Set ormtype on all keys.
4. Stick with int or integer and use it consistently.  I went with integer.
5. Occasionally restart everything/reboot.
6. I took the sqltype off of the foreign key reference in News.cfc

After I did all that, it finally started working as expected.

Here is my final News.cfc

```
/**
* Theser are the news items on the home page.
* @persistent true
* @accessors true
* @output false
* @entityname "News"
* @table news
*/

component
{
    property name="NewsId" type="string" fieldtype="id" ormtype="integer" generator="native" generated="insert";
    property name="Teaser" type="string" sqltype="varchar(200)";
    property name="Story" type="string" sqltype="varchar(500)";
    property name="ProductLine" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="ProductLine" ormtype="integer" fkcolumn="ProductLineId" foreignkeyname="fk_productline_news";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in News.cfc instead:

property name="productLine" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="ProductLine" fkcolumn="ProductLineID" foreignkeyname="fk_productline_news"

Comment: while this works and allows the cform export to complete, the relationship does not appear to exist in MySQL.  ProductLineId is still created as varchar(255).  It seems like that should be int

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an ormtype on your ProductLineID property in ProductLine.cfc? And I noticed you have "ormtype=int" in one place, and ormtype=integer in another.

Comment: Adding the ormtype="int" to ProductLine Id does seem to fix the datatype of the News table, but the relationship is still not created as far as I can tell. int vs integer should make no difference as they are synonyms in MySQL for the same thing, but I'll standardize on one.

Comment: one thing I noticed is that you have a "type=numeric" on your ProductLineID in the News component. You should probably take that off. I doubt it'll affect how hibernate creates the tables, however.